# Can i replace aws keys with IAM role in .aws/credentials for boto3 usage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I tried to use the role as:

```
~/.aws/credentials
[default]
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/yyyy
```

but i get error:

```
Partial credentials found in assume-role, missing: source_profile or credential_source
```

so it seems IAM role cannot replace

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
aws_secret_access_key =  BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

since as per http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html

```
# In ~/.aws/credentials:
[development]
aws_access_key_id=foo
aws_access_key_id=bar

# In ~/.aws/config
[profile crossaccount]
role_arn=arn:aws:iam:...
source_profile=development
```

I would still have to use keys, which could be a security risk, even though not being used in the code

Is there a way to use boto3 with admin privileges without using aws API credentials?

so basically:

1. Associate "admin" role to the ec2 instance, which you are going to use to run your boto3 scripts
2. Make sure it looks good. `$curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/`
3. test boto3 script

   #!/usr/bin/env python 
   import boto3
   ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
   def main():
       vpcs = ec2_client.describe_vpcs()
       for vpc_info in vpcs['Vpcs']:
           print(vpc_info['VpcId'])
   if **name** == "**main**":
       main()

I came across an Application on github which addresses this issue:

https://github.com/AdRoll/hologram

Comment: How would you propose that a client authenticate, without credentials?

Comment: @jarmod purpose is security ( DEVSECOPS ) not to expose AWS credentials.

Comment: There are still credentials. The appropriate way for EC2 to get credentials is to launch with an IAM role. This results in time-limited, auto-rotated credentials being made available on instance by the EC2 metadata service. Those credentials are available to any process on the EC2 instance and are auto-retrieved by all AWS SDKs (you don’t need a ~/.aws/config file for this to happen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have a role attached to the EC2 instance you can use:

~/.aws/config

```
[default]
credential_source=Ec2InstanceMetadata
```

---

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html

**credential_source** - The credential provider to use to get credentials for the initial assume-role call. This parameter cannot be provided alongside source_profile. Valid values are:

`Environment` to pull source credentials from environment variables.

`Ec2InstanceMetadata` to use the EC2 instance role as source credentials.

`EcsContainer` to use the ECS container credentials as the source credentials.

---

Comment: this solution works. This way we don't have to use aws keys and we can use this instance which has boto3 installed, to provision ec2 instances and do all tasks as boto3 API provides.

Comment: You don’t need to provide the ~/.aws/config file at all. All AWS SDKs will retrieve credentials from the IAM role, via the EC2 metadata service, by default.